# Import multiple .csv files into columns

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have VBA code that is extremely slow:

```
Sub getMoreSpeed(bDoIt As Boolean)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = Not (bDoIt)
    Application.EnableEvents = Not (bDoIt)
    Application.Calculation = IIf(bDoIt, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
    Application.Cursor = IIf(bDoIt, 2, -4143)
End Sub

    Sub import_0Grad()
Call getMoreSpeed(True)
            Dim fd As FileDialog
            Dim strFolder As String
            Dim strName As String
            Dim intCol As Integer
            Dim rngCell As Range
            Dim ws As Worksheet
            Dim varArr As Variant
            Dim i As Long

            Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3)

            Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
            If fd.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub

            strFolder = fd.SelectedItems(1) & "\"
            strName = Dir(strFolder & "*.csv")
            Set rngCell = ws.Cells(2, Columns.Count)

            While Len(strName) > 0
               If IsEmpty(rngCell.End(xlToLeft).Value) Then
                   intCol = 1
               Else:
                   intCol = rngCell.End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
               End If
               Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=strFolder & strName, Local:=True
               ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy ws.Cells(2, intCol)
               ws.Cells(1, intCol).Value = strName
               ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
               strName = Dir

               For i = 2 To ws.Cells(Rows.Count, intCol).End(xlUp).Row
                    varArr = Split(ws.Cells(i, intCol).Value, " ")
                    ws.Cells(i, intCol).Value = varArr(0)
                    ws.Cells(i, intCol + 1).Value = varArr(1)
               Next i
            Wend

            Set ws = Nothing
            Set fd = Nothing
            Set rngCell = Nothing

  Call getMoreSpeed(False)

    End Sub
```

Someone told me I should replace this, that divides the imported text into columns:

```
For i = 2 To ws.Cells(Rows.Count, intCol).End(xlUp).Row
                    varArr = Split(ws.Cells(i, intCol).Value, " ")
                    ws.Cells(i, intCol).Value = varArr(0)
                    ws.Cells(i, intCol + 1).Value = varArr(1)
               Next i
```

with the Text To Columns thing from the Excel macro recorder, but I have no idea what variables I need to put into the code. Using this should make it faster I guess but it needs to be customized.

```
Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Maybe someone can help me?

Comment: For `.csv` files, this should be enough and pretty efficient : `Workbooks.Open Filename:=strFolder & strName, Local:=True`. And you can get rid of your loop `For i = 2 To ...` ;)